# ASP.NET Core: Where to place uploaded images, which should be shared across solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, io

I have a webshop in ASP.MVC.
The solution consists of 2 projects - a web.frontend and a web.admin.

In web.admin, file upload is possible. These files should be accessible from the web.frontend to show in browser.

I have tried tons of different C# methods to various paths...

Please provide me a way to put shared files where the browser can access them too.

I've tried placing the files at the .sln root - but the browser gives me an error: Not allowed to load local resource.

So somehow, the files should be placed in the web.frontend wwwroot? from the web.admin project?

Comment: `The browser can access them, too` - Well, that would be using your web app to serve them to the browser, most likely from a directory or file share on a shared server

Answer (score 2):

Your only choice here is using virtual directories. In full IIS, that's a pretty straight-forward affair. You simply add a virtual directory to the site in IIS and point it to the location on the filesystem to where these files are stored. Then, you reference the files using this virtual directory in your HTML. For example:

```
<a href="/myvirtualdirectory/foo.txt">Foo</a>
```

The same is required in development, but the procedure is a bit more circuitous with IIS Express, since there's no GUI management. To add a virtual directory to your project in IIS Express, you'll need to go to  `File > New > Web Site...` in Visual Studio. Click the `Browse...` button, and then click on the `Local IIS` tab. Select the site for your project, and then click the icon at the top-right that looks like a yellow folder with a red asterisk. Type an alias name (this is what you'll use in your HTML) and then browse to the location of your files on the filesystem. Uncheck `Create IIS application` and then click `OK`. Then, click `Cancel` and `Cancel` again. You're not actually going to create a new website; it's just the only way to get to this area where you can add virtual directories. Rinse and repeat with your other project.